# WebSDR and continuous wave (CW) demodulation of DCF77 signal

Tags: modulation, dcf77

I am trying to receive DCF77 signal via WebSDR.
When I set CW demodulation I hear the sound even if I select the band with 0 width.

I am relatively new to the radio.
The question is why I do I hear the sound? I know that CW modulation is used for sending and receiving Morse code. To hear Morze code send with the CW modulation receiver must contain a zoomer to genrate audio when a radio wave is present. Does WebSDR generate a sound wave if the radio wave of DCF77 is present? (something like a zoomer).